# Fullcalendar scheduler not rendered correclty in lightning component

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, scheduler, salesforce-lightning

I try to implement fullcalendar scheduler in a salesforce lightning component.

Here the version and files of fullcalendar and scheduler I use:

```
<aura:component controller="SchedulerEvents" implements="force:appHostable" access="public">
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
        $Resource.fullcalendar310 +'/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js' ,
        $Resource.fullcalendar310 + '/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js',
        $Resource.fullcalendar310 + '/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.js',
        $Resource.fullcalendar310 + '/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js',
        $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/lib/jquery.min.js',
        $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/lib/fullcalendar.min.js' ,
        $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/lib/gcal.min.js' ,
        $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/lib/moment.min.js',
        $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/scheduler.js',
        $Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/scheduler.min.js'


        )}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsAreLoaded}"/>
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.fullcalendar310 + '/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.css'}"/>
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/scheduler.css'}"/>
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.fullcalendarScheduler161 + '/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.1/scheduler.min.css'}"/>

<aura:attribute name="events" type="Object[]" />
<div aura:id="scheduler"></div>
```

My javascript function setting up the calendar:

```
loadDataToCalendar :function(component,data){
    var ele = component.find('scheduler').getElement();
    $(ele).fullCalendar({
        defaultView:'timelineDay',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },

        navLinks: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
            { id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [
                { id: 'd1', title: 'Room D1' },
                { id: 'd2', title: 'Room D2' }
            ] },
            { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E' },
            { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
            { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
            { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H' },
            { id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I' },
            { id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J' },
            { id: 'k', title: 'Auditorium K' }
        ],
        events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-05-02T02:00:00', end: '2017-05-04T05:00:00', title: 'timed' },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2017-05-03', end: '2015-08-05', title: 'allday' }
        ],

       //groupByDateAndResource :true,
        groupbyresource:true,
        defaultDate: '2017-05-01',
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source'
    });
},
```

The standar day/week/month buttons work as expected and the events are shown correctly. My issue is when I set `defaultview` to `timelineDay` I get the following result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMsvd.jpg)

Day info and events per resource are missing. I tried different versions of libraries and js/css files but cannot make it work correctly. Any clue anyone?

Comment: why are you including jQuery twice, and including the moment, fullCalendar and scheduler files twice (the original and minified versions)? There's good chance this is causing some sort of conflict. Have you checked your console for warnings/errors? And why are you including the GCal library if you're not using Google Calendar? Sort out your dependencies and then see if you still have a problem.

Comment: P.S. I just noticed you're including the scheduler CSS twice as well (once full and once minified). Do you understand the difference between the expanded and minified files? They are alternative versions of the same content, not separate entities. The minified versions are useful for your live environment, when you don't need to debug but you want to provide the smallest possible download size for your end users.